# Add Social Links in Footer - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, social-buttons

I was trying to do something like this in my theme folder's default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_social_links">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="social.link" after="">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Contact Us</argument>
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string" translate="false">contact</argument>
        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">contact</argument>
    </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

It isn't working at the moment.  What I'm wanting to do is add some facebook icon and twitter icon linking to a specific page (pretty normal?).
I couldn't find other answers on the stackexchange here for Magento 2.

This was using XML code.  Do I need to do in PHTML?  I changed the "footer_links" to add custom links already with XML so I thought this was very similar that it would also be done in XML.

[image: Footer Appearance]

I want to add it along the right, under the subscribe section.  How do I implement, and then where do I put the styles?  _theme.less only and it links by just the class name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already added the `footer_social_links` block? `referenceBlock` should only be used with already defined blocks. If you haven't already created this block you'll need to add it using `block` instead of `referenceBlock`.

---

Personally I would add a template with your social media links/icons, then call this template within the XML. Like so:

```
<referenceBlock name="footer_social_links">
     <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="social.link" template="Magento_Theme::social-links.phtml" before="-"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

This creates a block within `footer_social_links`, this block uses the template in `Magento_Theme/templates/social-links.phtml` - Here you can add your content.

If this doesn't work then check that the block `footer_social_links` is displaying correctly.

Answer (score 2):

```
<referenceBlock name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer_social_links_block">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string" translate="true">dth_footer_social_links</argument>
            </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
```

In my `app/design/frontend/my_custom_name/theme_folder/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` I added the block above.  Then I made a static block inside the admin with of course block id of `dth_footer_social_links`

```
<div class="social-links" style="float: right; margin-right: 30px;">
  <a href="www.facebook.com/">DTH Facebook img here</a> <br />
  <a href="www.twitter.com/">DTH Twitter img here</a>
</div>
```

As you can see I used inline styles here, but I plan on moving these styles to the theme's less file that is _theme.less and using the class `social-links`.   For now inline-styles will work.