# How do I add a new Facebook link to new website

Tags: magento2, facebook

How do I easily add a Facebook link to a Facebook icon already in the footer? FYI first time using magento and not a developer.

Answer (score 0):

I think someone gives this answer before so, you check this :

[Add Social Links in Footer - Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121866/add-social-links-in-footer-magento-2)

https://webkul.com/blog/call-custom-block-links-footer-magento-2/

https://www.facebook.com/business/help/532749253576163

Create a block

Under Content > Blocks click the Add New Block button.

Block Title: Footer Links Block
Identifier: footer_links_block
Store View: choose your store view
Add your custom link list in the content. For example:

Link 1
    Link 2

Save
Create a widget
Under Content > Widgets, click the Add Widget button.

Type: CMS Block

Design Package/Theme: choose your theme then click Continue
Widget Title: Footer Links

Assign to store views : choose your store view
Click the Add Layout Update button and choose "Display on All Pages"
In the container dropdown, choose "CMS Footer Links"
In the "Widget options" tab on the left, click Select Block and choose your "Footer Links Block"
Save

Don't forget to flush the cache.

Answer (score 0):

1.Login to Magento Admin Panel:** Go to your Magento admin panel and log in.

2.Navigate to CMS Blocks:** In the admin panel, navigate to "Content" > "Blocks".

3.Edit Footer Block:** Find and edit the block that contains the footer information. This might be named something like "Footer" or "Footer Links".

4.Edit the HTML:** Inside the block's content, locate the HTML code for the Facebook icon. It might be an `<img>` tag or an icon class.

5.Add the Link:** Wrap the icon code with an anchor (`<a>`) tag and set the `href` attribute to your Facebook page URL. For example:

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/yourpage" target="_blank">
    <!-- Your Facebook icon code here -->
    <img src="facebook-icon.png" alt="Facebook">
</a>
```

6.Save Changes:** After adding the link, save your changes to the block.

7.Clear Cache:** Clear the Magento cache to ensure the changes take effect.

This is a general guideline and the exact steps might vary slightly depending on your Magento version and theme.